# How to change Java Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Hi I am developing a library management system in net-beans. When I run it on my system it works fine however, if try to run it on another system it gives me an error of javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("path_to_database_on_my_system"). But this pat[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpDQ1.png)h to database must be changed in this function. How would I do this?  Need Help.

Comment: did you try to store libraryDB file in resources?

Comment: Hi, The libraryDB is in main folder where all the folders like build,dist,nbproject,src and test are there. However when we clean and build, it goes in dist folder. Help please